# Can I use a Shimano XT 11-gear derailleur with a 10 ring cassette on a mountainbike?

Tags: gears, cassette, compatibility

I put a 40-11T 10-gear cassette on my mountainbike, but did not check whether it was compatible with my current xt shadow+ derailleur. Now the derailleur rubs against the cassette in higher gears. In the future I would like to put on an 11-gear cassette. 
So that I don't have to buy a new derailleur now and then again in a year or so I would like to install a derailleur that will work with both.
Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: You need a more complete description of your drivetrain.

Comment: I've got a Sunrace 40-11T 10-speed cassette. XT shadow+ 10-speed derailleur. XT-chain and RaceFace narrow-wide single chainring. I researched the derailleur, looks like max cassette is 36. I was not aware of that when I installed the new Sunrace 40-11T. Strange thing is, when I first did the changes, it all worked fine. After a ride on a trail the derailleur began rubbing against the cassette. After trying to bend the derailleur and hanger it started working again after a trip in the forest. I now seem to have full function. Don't know why. But it works and gonna ride the morrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 and 11 speed systems are not compatible. The pull ratio of the shifters is different, as is the cog spacing of the clusters.

You may get away with some combinations of frankien-mixandmatch, but as the drive chain wears, the differences become more problematic. Ultimately, most find its not worth the problems it creates.